# A short film of someone trying to fight off tiny Lemming-like beings invading their home

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I have a vague recollection of a short film I *think* I saw at some point post 2000.  It's possible I originally saw it on YouTube.

I believe it was CGI, and the aesthetic in [this short film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raeN1msvu3A) reminds me of it.

It's about someone (a guy?) attempting to defend their home (a flat apartment, I think) from tiny Lemming-like invaders that keep marching, constantly.  They may have been aiming to steal something (possibly food, I'm not really sure).  I vaguely recall a scene of them marching up the side of a building.

I don't really remember what the invaders looked like except that they were very small.

Comment: Not [The Trouble with Tribbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles)? or the animated [More Tribbles, More Troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Tribbles,_More_Troubles)

Comment: @bob1 I'm afraid it's definitely not those!  I remember them well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for!  It's a CGI short film called "Night of the Living Dead Pixels", uploaded to YouTube back in 2007.

You can view it here [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl6mmBvT24g):

Sadly there's only a low-quality version.  It looks like the high-quality version (linked from the video description) has long since disappeared from the internet and is not archived on archive.org as far as I can tell.  Still, mystery solved!